# What is the difference between exponent, power and index?

Tags: terminology, exponentiation

I have read that, if $$b=a\times a\times a\times \cdots \times a \text{ ($n$ times})$$ then $$b=a^n$$ where $b$ is known as the base, $n$ as the index or exponent and $b$ is the power.
The author in many places refers to both $b$ and $n$ as powers. **Is this correct?** **Is there any difference between exponent, index and power**?

Comment: $b$ is **`a`** power of $a$ means that there is $n$ for which $a^n=b$. While $n$ is **`the`** power of $a$ means we are talking about $a^n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, terminologies here can be confusing.  I would call $n$ the "exponent".  But one might speak of $b$ as "$a$ to the power $n$" (which makes it sound like $n$ is the "power"), or
"the $n$'th power of $a$" (which makes it sound like $b$ is the "power").

Comment: And a^n is the power. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Most sources would go with the model in the picture below, however many of those sources lack an unambiguous explanation. The "power" is not a "visible thing" more than it is a way of saying what the exponent is doing with the base. So in the image there are only two things, the exponent and the base. Together they form a power.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br7PN.jpg)